# Gulp "Task never defined: default"

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

how to fix my problem?
Here is my gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const webp = require('gulp-webp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

const origin = 'app';
const destination = 'app';

gulp.task('webp', () =>
gulp
.src(`${origin}/img/**`)
.pipe(webp())
.pipe(gulp.dest(`${destination}/img`))
);

gulp.task('live', function () {
gulp.watch('**/*.css').on('change', function () {
browserSync.reload();
 });
});
```

And here is my package.json

```json
{
 "name": "gulp-browsersync",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "watch": "node-sass --watch app/scss -o app/css"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
   "browser-sync": "^2.26.10",
   "gulp": "^4.0.2",
   "gulp-webp": "^4.0.1",
   "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
 },
 "dependencies": {}
 }
```

And this is my terminal log

> ```
> [13:39:25] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\gulp-browsersync-main\gulpfile.js
> [13:39:25] Task never defined: default
> [13:39:25] To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `exports` a function as `default` from your `gulpfile.js`

check [gulp-doc](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start/#create-a-gulpfile) and [creating-tasks](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks#exporting)

gulp need a function to start tasks and you must `exports.default` your main task function.
if you have multiple tasks you need to use `series` or `parallel`.

code:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const webp = require('gulp-webp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

const origin = 'app';
const destination = 'app';



function defaultTask(cb) {
    gulp.task('webp', () =>
        gulp
            .src(`${origin}/img/**`)
            .pipe(webp())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(`${destination}/img`))
    );

    gulp.task('live', function () {
        gulp.watch('**/*.css').on('change', function () {
            browserSync.reload();
        });
    });

    cb();
}

exports.default = defaultTask
```

Comment: If i do something like that i got this error in terminal
[14:00:42] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\gulp-browsersync-main\gulpfile.js
[14:00:42] Starting 'default'...
[14:00:42] The following tasks did not complete: default
[14:00:42] Did you forget to signal async completion?